# Are these HTML tags semantically correct?

Tags: html, semantics

I'm starting at web development and want to divide the content of one page in 2 columns, but I'm not sure if the following HTML semantics are correct.

```
<body>
<div class="left">
<section>
<h2>One</h2>
<img ...>
</section>
<section>
<h2>Two</h2>
<img...>
</section>
</div>
<div class="right">
<section>
<h2>Image related to those of the other div</h2>
<img...>
</section>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking the "*best way*" for anything are largely opinion-based and explicitly out of scope for Stack Overflow per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: The semantics of the elements are really dependent on the content.  What do you plan on putting in those two columns?

Comment: Just images and some text describing each of the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case your page is missing an `h1` tag, which is essential for semantics, SEO and accessibility!

The rest, for the described purpose of presenting some images, seems okay. You wouldn't necessarily have to use `section` tags, though – the `h2` tags are enough to organize them as images with related headers. But if those parts of the page are really thematically different, sections are a good way to emphasize that.